# How to call toString on iterator c++

Tags: c++, vector, tostring

hello I am new to coding so sorry for any misunderstandings I might have and how awful it looks. I have spent hours on this problem and cannot fix it. I have a vector of XMLItems and a constant toString method. When I try to call the toString with the iterator, it prints out nothing.

```
string XMLParser::toStringInput() const
{

string inputret = "";

  for(std::vector<XMLItem>::const_iterator iter = theInput.begin(); iter != theInput.end(); ++iter)
  {
  inputret += (*iter).toString();
  }
return inputret;
}
```

this returns nothing. Am I using the Iterator wrong? have I saved the string wrong when I created my vectors? Here's the toString in the XMLItem class

```
string XMLItem::toString() const
{
cout << this->theItem; //the item is a private string
return this->theItem;
}
```

here's where I created the vector just in case.

```
void XMLParser::readXML(Scanner& inStream)
{
string tmp = "";
string tag = "tag";
string data = "data";
XMLItem localxml = XMLItem();

while (inStream.hasNext())
{
string input = inStream.nextLine();

if(input.find("<") != std::string::npos)
{
  XMLItem localxml = XMLItem(tag, input);
}
else
{
  XMLItem localxml = XMLItem(data, input);
}

this->theInput.push_back(localxml);
}
}
```

Comment: There is so much going on here that we couldn't possibly know what in particular the problem is. Have you verified that you are actually iterating over the xml doc? Do you know it actually contains data? Try printing something out inside your iterator that should always print e.g. std::cout << "iterating" << std::endl;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You're pushing a local stack object into the container.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for the replies. It was the way I was creating my vector.

Answer (score 0):

```
XMLItem localxml = XMLItem();
while (inStream.hasNext()) {
  string input = inStream.nextLine();
  if(input.find("<") != std::string::npos) {
    XMLItem localxml = XMLItem(tag, input);
  } else {
    XMLItem localxml = XMLItem(data, input);
  }    
  this->theInput.push_back(localxml);
}
```

In both the block for the `if` and the one for the `else` case you have a new local (to that respective block) variable named `localxml`. They shadow the variable defined before the `while` loop, leaving it unchanged. So you basically could run

```
theInput.push_back(XMLItem());
```

inside that loop. So later, when you try to convert the elements of the vector to a string these "empty" elements get converted, probably leading to some empty strings being concatenated.

To fix that change the variable declarations to assignments by removing the type in front of the variable name:

```
localxml = XMLItem(tag, input);
```